# Microsoft Graph API - /memberOf not returning resourceProvisioningOptions for one group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm experiencing that me/memberOf is not returning the property resourceProvisioningOptions for one group that I'm a member of.  I'm using that property to check whether this group is a team.
All data looks to be the same as other groups that are returning this property.

Anyone else that have had this issue?

Calling me/joinedTeams returns this group/team just fine.
I can access the group fine within MS Teams as a member of this group.

Comment: if it's unused old team, In some document mention "Certain unused old teams will not have resourceProvisioningOptions set ".Ref doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams#get-a-list-of-groups

Answer (score 0):

As per the document, If it's unused old team "Certain unused old teams will not have resourceProvisioningOptions set. "
Ref. Doc:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams#get-a-list-of-groups